# Spring Data Redis repository won't work with queries with Lists

Tags: java, spring, jpa, redis, spring-data

I have been trying to use Spring Data Redis but it fails for queries with List in them and just won't work. I tested it with normal fields such as ID and it works fine without issues, would appreciate it if someone can look at my code, thanks!

I have the following model:

```java
@RedisHash("Flight")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Flight implements Serializable {
    @Id
    private String id;
    @Indexed
    private List<String> dayOfWeek;
}
```

But when I try to define a query in my repository as follows:

```
@Repository
public interface FlightRepository extends CrudRepository<Flight, String> {
    List<Flight> findFlightsByDayOfWeek(List<String> dayOfWeek);
}
```

It throws the following exception when called:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [byte] for value 'Monday'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Monday"
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.ConversionUtils.invokeConverter(ConversionUtils.java:47)
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:192)
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.CollectionToArrayConverter.convert(CollectionToArrayConverter.java:75)
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.ConversionUtils.invokeConverter(ConversionUtils.java:41)
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:192)
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:175)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisQueryEngine.keys(RedisQueryEngine.java:202)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisQueryEngine.lambda$doFind$0(RedisQueryEngine.java:102)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate.execute(RedisTemplate.java:223)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate.execute(RedisTemplate.java:190)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate.execute(RedisTemplate.java:177)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisKeyValueAdapter.execute(RedisKeyValueAdapter.java:597)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisQueryEngine.doFind(RedisQueryEngine.java:139)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisQueryEngine.execute(RedisQueryEngine.java:81)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisQueryEngine.execute(RedisQueryEngine.java:52)
    at org.springframework.data.keyvalue.core.QueryEngine.execute(QueryEngine.java:73)
    at org.springframework.data.keyvalue.core.AbstractKeyValueAdapter.find(AbstractKeyValueAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.data.keyvalue.core.KeyValueTemplate.lambda$find$6(KeyValueTemplate.java:395)
    at org.springframework.data.keyvalue.core.KeyValueTemplate.execute(KeyValueTemplate.java:362)
    at org.springframework.data.keyvalue.core.KeyValueTemplate.executeRequired(KeyValueTemplate.java:377)
    at org.springframework.data.keyvalue.core.KeyValueTemplate.find(KeyValueTemplate.java:393)
    at org.springframework.data.keyvalue.repository.query.KeyValuePartTreeQuery.doExecute(KeyValuePartTreeQuery.java:136)
    at org.springframework.data.keyvalue.repository.query.KeyValuePartTreeQuery.execute(KeyValuePartTreeQuery.java:110)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:137)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:121)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:159)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:138)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:80)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy66.findFlightsByDayOfWeek(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy66.findFlightsByDayOfWeek(Unknown Source)
    at com.distributed.airways.Application.initDatabase(Application.java:25)
    at com.distributed.airways.Application.main(Application.java:18)
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Monday"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
    at java.lang.Byte.parseByte(Byte.java:149)
    at java.lang.Byte.valueOf(Byte.java:205)
    at java.lang.Byte.valueOf(Byte.java:231)
    at org.springframework.util.NumberUtils.parseNumber(NumberUtils.java:205)
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.StringToNumberConverterFactory$StringToNumber.convert(StringToNumberConverterFactory.java:64)
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.StringToNumberConverterFactory$StringToNumber.convert(StringToNumberConverterFactory.java:50)
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService$ConverterFactoryAdapter.convert(GenericConversionService.java:437)
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.ConversionUtils.invokeConverter(ConversionUtils.java:41)
    ... 46 more
```

Comment: Forgetting JPA for a moment, how would you _manually_ write the query statement to retrieve the list of flights using a list of `dayOfWeek`?

Comment: hmm I'd say create sets with name `Flight:dayOfWeek:Thursday` and group the ids into each set? So when querying I can just check the set with name `Flight:dayOfWeek:Thursday` and return all matching entries. But this becomes complicated if I plan to include more stuff such as `List<Flight> findFlightsByDayOfWeek(List<String> dayOfWeek, String airport);`

Comment: Right. JPA can't create that complication without your help. So you'll have to write a custom query and apply that to your method so that JPA can interpret your intent.